# How to access runtime queueLength parameter from c++ code in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I need to assign cost of OSPF according to queueLength of routers. So how to access this statistic form C++ code? This statistic has defined in `PacketQueue.ned` that is used in `ppp` in router. According to OMNeT++ manual documentation I should use

```
cPar& queueLengthPar = par("queueLength");
```

but I don't know is this true?
The code that OSPF uses for cost calculation in `OspfConfigReader.cc` in inet framework is :

```
Ospfv2Interface *intf = new Ospfv2Interface;
Metric cost = getIntAttrOrPar(ifConfig, "interfaceOutputCost");
if(cost == 0)
   intf->setOutputCost(round(par("referenceBandwidth").intValue() / ie.getDatarate()));
else
   intf->setOutputCost(cost);
```

I should modify the code according to `queueLength` statistic like this:

```
Ospfv2Interface *intf = new Ospfv2Interface;
Metric cost = getIntAttrOrPar(ifConfig, "interfaceOutputCost");
if(cost == 0)
   intf->setOutputCost(par("queueLength"));
else
   intf->setOutputCost(cost);
```

but the error is `unknown parameter "queueLength"`. Where should i a should add this statistic correctly?

`myNet.ned file is:

package secondproject.simulations;

```
    import inet.common.misc.ThruputMeteringChannel;
    import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
    import inet.networklayer.ipv4.Ipv4RoutingTable;
    import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
    import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
    import inet.node.ospfv2.OspfRouter;
    import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedVisualizer;
    import inet.visualizer.linklayer.InterfaceTableVisualizer;


    network myNet
    {
        parameters:
             @display("p=10,10;b=712,152;bgb=1051.64,508.58002");
        types:
             channel C extends ThruputMeteringChannel
             {
                 datarate = 10Gbps;
                 delay = 1ns;
                 thruputDisplayFormat = "#N";
             }
    
             channel Channel extends ThruputMeteringChannel
             {
                 datarate = 10Gbps;
                 delay = 1ns;
                 thruputDisplayFormat = "#N";
             }

       submodules:
           rtr: RoutingTableRecorder {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=40.945,475.1775;is=s");
           }
           H1: StandardHost {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=107.75,31.2475");
               gates:
                   ethg[1];
           }
           R1: OspfRouter {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=248.9025,103.44");
               gates:
                   ethg[3];
           }
           R2: OspfRouter {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=466.5575,103.44");
               gates:
                   ethg[4];
           }
           R3: OspfRouter {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=668.05,103.44");
               gates:
                   ethg[4];
          }
          R4: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=886.78253,103.44");
              gates:
                  ethg[3];
          }
          H4: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=1029.0125,22.6275");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          R5 OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=248.9025,187.485");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R6: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=466.5575,191.795");
              gates:
          ethg[4];
          }
          R7: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=668.05,187.485");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R8: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=886.78253,187.485");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R9: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=248.9025,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R10: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=466.5575,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R11: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=668.05,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R12: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=886.78253,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R13: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=248.9025,372.815");
              gates:
                  ethg[3];
          }
          R14: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=466.5575,372.815");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R15: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=668.05,372.815");
              gates:
                  ethg[4];
          }
          R16: OspfRouter {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=886.78253,372.815");
              gates:
                  ethg[3];
          }
          H9: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=82.9675,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H13: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=159.47,466.5575");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H2: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=466.5575,22.6275");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H12: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=1027.935,277.995");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H16: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=1027.935,483.79752");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H15: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=668.05,461.17");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H14: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=466.5575,461.17");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H3: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=668.05,22.6275");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H5: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=82.9675,187.485");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          H8: StandardHost {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=1027.935,187.485");
              gates:
                  ethg[1];
          }
          configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
              parameters:
                  @display("p=40.945,103.44;is=s");
                  config = xml("<config>"
                                    + "<interface among='H1 R1' address='192.168.1.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H2 R2' address='192.168.2.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H3 R3' address='192.168.3.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H4 R4' address='192.168.4.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H5 R5' address='192.168.5.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H8 R8' address='192.168.8.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H9 R9' address='192.168.9.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H12 R12' address='192.168.12.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H13 R13' address='192.168.13.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H14 R14' address='192.168.14.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H15 R15' address='192.168.15.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='H16 R16' address='192.168.16.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<interface among='R*' address='10.0.0.x' netmask='255.255.255.x' />"
                                    + "<multicast-group hosts='R*' address='224.0.0.5 224.0.0.6' />"                      
                                    + "<route hosts='H1' destination='*' gateway='R1'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H2' destination='*' gateway='R2'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H3' destination='*' gateway='R3'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H4' destination='*' gateway='R4'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H5' destination='*' gateway='R5'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H8' destination='*' gateway='R8'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H9' destination='*' gateway='R9'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H12' destination='*' gateway='R12'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H13' destination='*' gateway='R13'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H14' destination='*' gateway='R14'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H15' destination='*' gateway='R15'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='H16' destination='*' gateway='R16'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='R*' destination='224.0.0.0' netmask='240.0.0.0' interface='eth0'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='R*' destination='224.0.0.0' netmask='240.0.0.0' interface='eth1'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='R*' destination='224.0.0.0' netmask='240.0.0.0' interface='eth2'/>"
                                    + "<route hosts='R2 R3 R5 R6 R7 R8 R9 R10 R11 R12 R14 R15' destination='224.0.0.0' netmask='240.0.0.0' interface='eth3'/>"
                                    + "</config>");
    }


       connections:
           R1.ethg[0] <--> C <--> R2.ethg[0];
           R1.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R5.ethg[0];
           R1.ethg[2] <--> Channel <--> H1.ethg[0];
           R2.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R3.ethg[0];
           R2.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R6.ethg[0];
           R2.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H2.ethg[0];
           R3.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R4.ethg[0];
           R3.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R7.ethg[0];
           R3.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H3.ethg[0];
           R4.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R8.ethg[0];
           R4.ethg[2] <--> Channel <--> H4.ethg[0];
           R5.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R6.ethg[1];
           R5.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R9.ethg[0];
           R5.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H5.ethg[0];
           R6.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R7.ethg[1];
           R6.ethg[3] <--> C <--> R10.ethg[0];
           R7.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R8.ethg[1];
           R7.ethg[3] <--> C <--> R11.ethg[0];
           R8.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R12.ethg[0];
           R8.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H8.ethg[0];
           R9.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R10.ethg[1];
           R9.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R13.ethg[0];
           R9.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H9.ethg[0];
           R10.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R11.ethg[1];
           R10.ethg[3] <--> C <--> R14.ethg[0];
           R11.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R12.ethg[1];
           R11.ethg[3] <--> C <--> R15.ethg[0];
           R12.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R16.ethg[0];
           R12.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H12.ethg[0];
           R13.ethg[1] <--> C <--> R14.ethg[1];
           R13.ethg[2] <--> Channel <--> H13.ethg[0];
           R14.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R15.ethg[1];
           R14.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H14.ethg[0];
           R15.ethg[2] <--> C <--> R16.ethg[1];
           R15.ethg[3] <--> Channel <--> H15.ethg[0];
           R16.ethg[2] <--> Channel <--> H16.ethg[0];
    }
```

`omnetpp.ini` is:

```
    [General]
    network = myNet
    eventlog-file = ${resultdir}/${configname}-${iterationvarsf}#${repetition}.elog
    record-eventlog = true
    sim-time-limit = 10s

    **.ospf.ospfConfig = xmldoc("ASConfig.xml")
    **.ospf.helloInterval = 1s
    **.ospf.retransmissionInterval = 1s

    **.H*.numApps = 2
    **.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
    **.app[0].destPort = 1234
    **.app[0].messageLength = 1000 bytes
    **.app[0].sendInterval = 1us
    **.app[0].startTime = 2s
    **.app[0].stopTime = this.startTime + 90s
    **.H1.app[0].destAddresses = "H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H2.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H3.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H4.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H5.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H8.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H9.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H12.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H13 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H13.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H14 H15 H16"
    **.H14.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H15 H16"
    **.H15.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H16"
    **.H16.app[0].destAddresses = "H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H8 H9 H12 H13 H14 H15"

    **.app[1].typename = "UdpSink"
    **.app[1].localPort = 1234


    **.configurator.addStaticRoutes = false
    **.configurator.addSubnetRoutes = false
    **.configurator.addDefaultRoutes = false
    **.configurator.dumpRoutes = true
```

my `ASConfig.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OSPFASConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="OSPF.xsd">

  <!-- Areas -->
  <Area id="0.0.0.0">
    <AddressRange address="R1>R2" mask="R1>R2" />
    <AddressRange address="R1>R5" mask="R1>R5" />
    <AddressRange address="R2>R1" mask="R2>R1" />
    <AddressRange address="R2>R3" mask="R2>R3" />
    <AddressRange address="R2>R6" mask="R2>R6" />
    <AddressRange address="R3>R2" mask="R3>R2" />
    <AddressRange address="R3>R4" mask="R3>R4" />
    <AddressRange address="R3>R7" mask="R3>R7" />
    <AddressRange address="R4>R3" mask="R4>R3" />
    <AddressRange address="R4>R8" mask="R4>R8" />
    <AddressRange address="R5>R1" mask="R5>R1" />
    <AddressRange address="R5>R6" mask="R5>R6" />
    <AddressRange address="R5>R9" mask="R5>R9" />
    <AddressRange address="R6>R2" mask="R6>R2" />
    <AddressRange address="R6>R5" mask="R6>R5" />
    <AddressRange address="R6>R7" mask="R6>R7" />
    <AddressRange address="R6>R10" mask="R6>R10" />
    <AddressRange address="R7>R3" mask="R7>R3" />
    <AddressRange address="R7>R6" mask="R7>R6" />
    <AddressRange address="R7>R8" mask="R7>R8" />
    <AddressRange address="R7>R11" mask="R7>R11" />
    <AddressRange address="R8>R4" mask="R8>R4" />
    <AddressRange address="R8>R7" mask="R8>R7" />
    <AddressRange address="R8>R12" mask="R8>R12" />
    <AddressRange address="R9>R5" mask="R9>R5" />
    <AddressRange address="R9>R10" mask="R9>R10" />
    <AddressRange address="R9>R13" mask="R9>R13" />
    <AddressRange address="R10>R6" mask="R10>R6" />
    <AddressRange address="R10>R9" mask="R10>R9" />
    <AddressRange address="R10>R11" mask="R10>R11" />
    <AddressRange address="R10>R14" mask="R10>R14" />
    <AddressRange address="R11>R7" mask="R11>R7" />
    <AddressRange address="R11>R10" mask="R11>R10" />
    <AddressRange address="R11>R12" mask="R11>R12" />
    <AddressRange address="R11>R15" mask="R11>R15" />
    <AddressRange address="R12>R8" mask="R12>R8" />
    <AddressRange address="R12>R11" mask="R12>R11" />
    <AddressRange address="R12>R16" mask="R12>R16" />
    <AddressRange address="R13>R9" mask="R13>R9" />
    <AddressRange address="R13>R14" mask="R13>R14" />
    <AddressRange address="R14>R10" mask="R14>R10" />
    <AddressRange address="R14>R13" mask="R14>R13" />
    <AddressRange address="R14>R15" mask="R14>R15" />
    <AddressRange address="R15>R11" mask="R15>R11" />
    <AddressRange address="R15>R14" mask="R15>R14" />
    <AddressRange address="R15>R16" mask="R15>R16" />
    <AddressRange address="R16>R12" mask="R16>R12" />
    <AddressRange address="R16>R15" mask="R16>R15" />

  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.1">
    <AddressRange address="H1" mask="H1" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.2">
    <AddressRange address="H2" mask="H2" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.3">
    <AddressRange address="H3" mask="H3" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.4">
    <AddressRange address="H4" mask="H4" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.5">
    <AddressRange address="H5" mask="H5" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.8">
    <AddressRange address="H8" mask="H8" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.9">
    <AddressRange address="H9" mask="H9" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.12">
    <AddressRange address="H12" mask="H12" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.13">
    <AddressRange address="H13" mask="H13" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.14">
    <AddressRange address="H14" mask="H14" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.15">
    <AddressRange address="H15" mask="H15" />
  </Area>

  <Area id="0.0.0.16">
    <AddressRange address="H16" mask="H16" />
  </Area>

<!-- Routers -->
<Router name="R1" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.1" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R2" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.2" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R3" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.3" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R4" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.4" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R5" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.5" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R6" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R7" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R8" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.8" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R9" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.9" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R10" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R11" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R12" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.12" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R13" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.13" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R14" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.14" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R15" RFC1583Compatible="true">
  <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth3" areaID="0.0.0.15" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
</Router>

<Router name="R16" RFC1583Compatible="true">
    <BroadcastInterface ifName="eth2" areaID="0.0.0.16" />
    <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth0" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
    <PointToPointInterface ifName="eth1" areaID="0.0.0.0" />
  </Router>

</OSPFASConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the value of a parameter write:

```
int len = par("queueLength");
```

Comment: Thank you for yor reply. i did this and the error is: unknown parameter "queueLength". queueLength has defined in packetQueue.ned as parameter `@defaultStatistic(queueLength:vector);` and ppp has access to it. I use ppp interface in myNetwork. So should i define it again in my network.ned such `int queueLength;` or something else ?

Comment: another question is should i say the ospf to read myNetwork file in the manner `Define_Module(myNetwork)`?

Comment: The line `@defaultStatistic(queueLength:vector);` means that `queueLength` is a statistic, not a parameter. Could you edit your question and precise what do you want to read and provide [mcve]?

Comment: The question is: Can i access @statistic[queueLength] through c++ code?